# Hibernate avoid nullable unique fields in query?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having one hibernate pojo class which has 3 fields specified in `@UniqueConstraint` (unique together) where one of these 3 fields is `nullable=true`.

When I try to update entry with `session.update(pojo)` it updates all the entries in database which matches 2 fields (which are not nullable), so does hibernate avoid nullable fields while querying? or there is something what I should know about it?

**Edit: Added class**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "details",
uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"service_id", "billing_item_id", "service_type_id"}, name="UK_name_it")}      
    )
public class Detail implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_name2")
    @Id
    private Service service;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="billing_item_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_name3")
    @Id
    private BillingItem billingItem;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="currency_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_name4")
    private Currency currency;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="service_type_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_name5")
    private ServiceType serviceType;

    @Column(name = "completed", nullable = false)
    private boolean completed;
}
```

Comment: You will need to post your object structure, we can't really answer why this is happening without knowing specifics.

Comment: there are two @Id annotations in your Entity class which are forienn keys..which is your primary key

Comment: I added class which we are using, thanks!
BTW I tried adding `@Id` to serviceType field (which has to be null) then code considers this field in update query in where condition, but if I add `@Id` then this field can't be null, right?

Comment: @Lucky, I want service, billingItem and serviceType to be considered when updating entries in table Details, but serviceType has to be nullable, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any option like that to have a `nullable` field in composite key, so I had to end up by adding a integer `autoincrement` primary key to the table, and keeping service, billingItem and serviceType fields in `@UniqueConstraint`.

There is another option I could adopt, which is possible in certain scenarios, by adding a `serviceType` which is considered as `All` entry (basically when serviceType is null it applies to all the serviceTypes.) and instead of using `null` for serviceType point to this entry, this way we can have `PK` and no need to make serviceType a `nullable` field.